# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to false"  sonar issue on below code

```
UserTransaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext()
        .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    tx.begin();

    // ...

} catch (NamingException | NotSupportedException | SystemException | CommandException e) {
    Logger.logError(getClass(), e);
    try {
        if(null != tx) {
            tx.rollback(); // gives  Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException rollbackt) {
        logError("Rollback exception", rollbackt);
    }

    throw new UserDefinedException("failed save incomplete order due to a command exception", e);
}
```

any good idea we can handle this ?

Comment: So you roll back this transaction every time, do you?

Comment: That code will not compile, because `tx` is declared inside the `try` block and is not in scope inside the `catch` block. If code does compile, it may actually explain message, because it means you have *another* variable named `tx` that you initialized to `null`, and *that* variable is never assigned another value, so it's always `null`, and `if` statement will always be `false`.

Comment: Hi Andreas, you are right actually, tx is not define under try block. it is defined outside of try block.

Comment: Then edit question and show the *actual* code.

Comment: Hi Joe C, yes if we catch exception  (NamingException | NotSupportedException | SystemException | CommandException) we have to rollback.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have updated question

Comment: what version of SonarQube and SonarJava plugin do you use? Can you try to update to the latest version and verify if the issue persists?

Comment: I just run SonarQube Version 6.4 analysis and this issue is not being reported. The rule "Conditionally executed blocks should be reachable" is enabled in my profile.

Comment: @ Tibor, Thanks for reply. I am using Version 4.5.6.

Comment: @Boris. Thanks for reply! I will discuss with my architecture team if they are agree to update sonar version.

Answer (score -4):

here is an explanation to the issue reported by sonar lint. The section:

> if(null != tx) {
>               tx.rollback(); // gives  Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"  }

Here if you see the way you have written the condition **"null != tx"** as we know the property of "null" & if we will compare "null" to be equivalent to be anything that's not possible.

If the condition is written like:

> if(tx != null) {
>               tx.rollback(); 
>   }

The sonar lint issue will be fixed, as now instead of checking the value of null, the value of "tx" will be evaluated & if its now equal to null, the "tx.rollback()" will execute.

I hope this clarifies it all :)

Comment: This answer is wrong. `x != null` and `null != x` are logically equivalent, some just prefer the latter form for some reason.

Comment: Hi Rachana, Thanks for reply! I tried this but still it gives same issue.

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong, both syntax are equivalent and the analyzer will handle them the same way.